# E-mail message/body section won't change

Tags: php, email

I have a login form when the user registers it sends out an E-mail to activate the account. The problem is that the e-mail body section is not changing, my code to send out the E-mail looks like this

```
 $to ="$e";
 $from ="jalilmotaz@gmail";
 $subject = 'collegeloop activation';
 $body ="hi";
 $message="hi";
 $headers ='From: $from';
 mail($to, $message, $subject, $headers);
 echo "signup_success";
 exit();
```

when the E-mail is sent it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3CrY.jpg this is what the message originally was, but when I want to change it, as you see above It should say "hi" , it is not changing.

any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `$message` declared?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as it should, really.

You changed `$body` variable but message is in `$message`. Try to change correct variable ;)

Comment: Just tried it , Not working. it seems as if the older message is stuck. I edited the question to have $message.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a caching problem. PHP can cache the rendered pages to speed up performance and email body is rendered as an HTML like all other pages.
If you are using APC then use the following link to clear cache and try again,
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-configuration/view-and-clear-php-apc-cache

If your server is on linux, then you can try the following,

```
find . -name "*.php.cache" | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: I am using windows running on wamp server .

Comment: I still believe it is a caching problem. This code is simple and you are actually executing it, then the only reason why an older version will get picked up is because it is cached somewhere, either at PHP, or apache, or IMAP or Gmail server.